# how to get element inside frame? (to draw canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Page for Example:
http://google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

If i open the image 'myid' the frame will be - EXAMPLE:frame2

now what i want to do, is to draw canvas of 'myid' inside the 'frame2'.

here is the code that i have: (draw by element id)

```
var canvas = window.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',   'html:canvas');
var selection_element = window.document.getElementById("myid");
var selection;
var de = window.document.documentElement;
var box = selection_element.getBoundingClientRect();
var new_top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - de.clientTop;
var new_left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - de.clientLeft;
var new_height = selection_element.offsetHeight;
var new_width = selection_element.offsetWidth;
selection={
top:new_top,
left:new_left,
width:new_width,
height:new_height,
};
canvas.height = selection.height;
canvas.width = selection.width;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawWindow(
window,
selection.left,
selection.top,
selection.width,
selection.height,
'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
);
var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL('','').split(',')[1];
```

Comment: I do not know what you say, But to access an element in frame: `var frame = window.frames['YOUR-FRAME-ID'];
    $(frame).load(function ()
    {
        $(frame).contents().find('YOUR-CANVAS-ID`')

Comment: @Farzin Kanzii i can use something like this?     var canvas = window.frames.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',   'html:canvas');
var selection_element = window.frames.getElementById("myid");
var selection;
var de = window.frames.documentElement;

Comment: I do not know any thing about `createElementNS`. Does it work in other places?

Comment: @Farzin Kanzi yes, imacros javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append item to frame you need to call that by id. In this HTML:

```
<iframe id="frm1"></iframe>
<iframe id="frm2"></iframe>
```

If you use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var frames = window.frames;
        for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++)
        {
            var fi = frames[i]

            $(fi).load(function ()
            {
                $(this).contents().find('body').append("<span>Hello World!</span>");
            });
        }
    });
```

Does not work, But this one works:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <iframe id="frm1"></iframe>
   <iframe id="frm2"></iframe>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var frm1 = window.frames["frm1"];
        $(frm1).load(function ()
        {
            $(frm1).contents().find('body').append("<span>Hello World!</span>");
        });

    });
 </script>
 </body></html>
```

I tried to create a code snippet, but it seems it has problem with frames.

You can copy the exact HTML and test that.

Comment: Thank you! its didnt work for me but i think my question is more for imacros. so i try in imacros forum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096133/javascript-and-imacros-queryselectorall-is-undefined

Comment: Thanks for check.